# Insert After Delete Causing Integrity Constraint Violation1062 Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS MySQL table which has a unique key constraint. Let us take the table name as `user` and field name as `username` for example. Suppose the table has a row `username=admin`. I am executing the below queries using Laravel.

1. delete from user where username='admin'
2. insert into user (username) values ('admin')

Once in a while, I can see `Integrity Constraint Violation1062 Duplicate Entry` in the logs. It seems like the row is not deleted by the time the code executes the insert query. It works most of the time. I can update the code with other logic but wondering why it is happening! Is there any AWS RDS specific scenarios related to this use case? I have not experienced this using own MySQL installation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: wondering why you want to delete and then insert again into the same table!!! you can update the same record if you have a strong reason. right?

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy - my actual use case is entirely different. What I have given is a simple example. I can actually solve the issue in different ways but trying to find out the reason behind the issue!

Comment: did you check if a child relation exists on username? also check if `on delete ... no action` is controlling the action.

Comment: You may have oversimplified your problem (especially if your "actual use case is entirely different"). If you execute those two queries successfully and in that order, this should not happen. The first query might have failed, you may do this in a different order and/or different session/transactions, maybe indirectly by using a connection pool or asyncronous execution, or maybe yet another session also tries to insert that username. This might only happen on rds (in contrast to e.g. localhost) because of load/connection delay or just by chance.

Comment: Thanks,  Solarflare, and Ravinder Reddy. Let me go through the query logs.